# How to implement SHA 1 Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, security

i want to implement SHA 1 Algorithm using java.
Can any one help me

---

[Refer this](http://www.codase.com/search/display?file=L2dlbnRvbzIvdmFyL3RtcC9yZXBvcy9zb3VyY2Vmb3JnZS9zYWZlc21zL1NhZmVTTVNfdGFyX2d6L1NIQTEuamF2YQ==&lang=java)

Comment: http://www.codase.com/search/display?file=L2dlbnRvbzIvdmFyL3RtcC9yZXBvcy9zb3VyY2Vmb3JnZS9zYWZlc21zL1NhZmVTTVNfdGFyX2d6L1NIQTEuamF2YQ==&lang=java

Comment: Do you want to implement it from scratch or you want to call it from some library?

Comment: Why? A hand-rolled version is almost certain to be less secure and have more bugs than a version that has been implemented by security professionals and reviewed many times by *other* security professionals.

Comment: Maybe it's homework or just plain interest.

Comment: There's plenty of code snippets that can be easily found with a simple web search. If you have more specific questions or concerns, please add them when submitting your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure quite what you're asking; Wikipedia has pseudo-code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1  you should be able to code it up in java from that relativly easily... Did you have any specific question about doing it, or...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `java.security.MessageDigest`. For ASCII data this is as simple as

```java
String src = ...
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
String sha1 = new String(md.digest(src.getBytes()));
```

Comment: I think you forgot the () on the `getBytes()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do it, load the [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) libraries and use them. Or look at their source, and then you know one way how to implement it :).

Comment: It's possible that the want to implement it in order to understand how it works, without wanting to use it in production.